# Setting the position of my ball

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm learning how to use **SpriteKit**.

**Question:**

As practice, I'm trying to make a mock of pong. I want the ball's initial position to be in the center, and for the life of me, I cannot set its position to be in the center. It always ends up in the bottom left hand corner of the screen and I have no clue why. I've set the scene's scale mode equal to `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill`, and I've tried each of the following lines of code in separate trials in order to get set its position to the center, but it has always remained in that bottom left hand corner.

```
    //Attempt #1
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)); //find the middle of each axis and put them together in one coordinate
    //Attempt #2
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2); //find the width and height of the screen, divide each by 2 and assign them to an (x,y) coordinate together
    //Attempt #3
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(160, 284) //Half the width and half the height
    //Attempt #4
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(320, 568) //The width and the height (I'm desperately guessing at this point)
    //Attempt #5
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(0,0) //I figured I'd give it a go
```

This ball is an `SKSpriteNode` by the way I didn't make a `Ball` subclass of `SKSpriteNode` or anything. The strange thing about this, is I've been able to bring up other sprites on the screen such as paddles and scores exactly where I want them. It's just this ball that isn't cooperating. What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this issue in the future?

Comment: You are probably setting the position at the wrong point. Please add some code related to the ball node's initialization, along with the block you are doing so in.

Comment: "This ball is an SKSpriteNode by the way I didn't make a Ball subclass of SKSpriteNode or anything." So is `Ball` an SKSpriteNode or not? Give us more code instead of trying to describe how do you create objects

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make ball's initial position to centre, then write below code:

```
 [self.ball setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];
```

I'm using above code in my code and it is giving me perfect result.

Let me know it is working or not?

Happy Coding!

Comment: You probably mean self.frame.size.width or similar.

Comment: Oh wow I'm dumb. I was trying to set the ball's position before I set its color and size.